# Allowing only one update for specific param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

How can I make it so once a param is filled, it can't be updated or edited again?

**Issue:** I have a param, :video, that once filled it will charge the customer.  I want to make it so once it's filled, it can't be updated or edited again.

I have taken preventative measures on the views side that once a video is uploaded the edit/update form is hidden and can't be created again but one thing i noticed that if an update fails for any reason, the page can be went back to and the update form can be filled out again (even if the video is uploaded), thus again charging the customer twice.

**How it works:** 
A customer creates an order, a stripe id is created, once the seller fulfills the order (by uploading a file or video), the charge is captured.

```
  def charge_update
    respond_to do |format|
      @amount = (@order.order_price).to_i * 100
      @amount_seller = (@order.order_price).to_i * 75
      if @order.update(order_charge)
        begin
                      charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
                        :amount      => (@order.order_price).to_i * 100,
                        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
                        :currency    => 'usd',
                        :customer => @order.stripe_customer_token,
                        :destination => {
                          :amount => @amount_seller ,
                          :account => (@order.seller.stripe_token),
                        }
                      })
                    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
                      charge_error = e.message
                    end
          @order.update_column(:order_status, 2)
          format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order was successfully uploaded.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
        elsif
          if charge_error
            flash[:error] = charge_error
            redirect_to user_order_path([@user, @order])
          else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
private

def order_charge
      params.require(:order).permit(:video, :order_status)
    end
```

Feel free to let me know if there is a better way to go about validating the charge on the customer. My biggest concern is a customer being charged more than once because a seller either messes up, is malicious, etc.  I want to guarantee a customer will only be charged once.   The only way I can think of is to only allow one update to the video column.

Either that or creating a separate table for videos with order_id being unique to each video table ID.

UPDATE

I ended up doing the following which works... If any has any ideas of a better way, I am open to suggestions!

```
def charge_update
    respond_to do |format|
    if @order.video.present?
      format.html { redirect_to ([@user, @order]), notice: 'Order already completed!.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
    else
        @amount = (@order.order_price).to_i * 100
        @amount_seller = (@order.order_price).to_i * 75
        if @order.update(order_charge)
          begin
...
...
...
end
```

Comment: you mean that you want the customer to make only one order for one video and if he wants to make another order for the same video , it shouldn't work , am right ?

Comment: How it works is a customer requests a video from a seller - the seller then creates and uploads, then a charge is captured.  I'm worried about the seller accidentally or purposely creating multiple charges on a single order.  i want to make sure a seller can't upload a video, and then somehow overried that upload and upload another video, thus charging the customer twice.

Comment: you can make a table that has the user_id , video_id ,order_id and charged(boolean value) , once the customer made a purchase , you can  fill these values so the customer knows which video and the specific id of the order he made for that video

Comment: So basically once the video column is filled, it can't be updated, edit, deleted, etc (unless by admin or through a dev) - Do you think I should just create another table and make each video unique to a order_id?

Comment: okay, so another table is really the best way to go about it? Wanted to make sure there wasn't a way to do it through the existing table before going ahead and creating it...

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to make a table that has these values

```
order_id 
video_id 
user_id 
charged (Boolean Value )
```

once the customer made an order and charged it , you can fill these values and make charged value as true .

you can check if he made an order for that video before or not before making a new payment for it again .

here is an example for the model you can make for that

```
  class CustomerOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :video      
  end
```

before the customer make a new order , you can check if there is any relation

```
   @customerorder =CustomerOrder.where(video_id: @video.id , user_id: @user.id , charged :true )
```

Comment: To clarify further on how it works... a customer creates an order and their card is tested to see if they have funds available with no capture.. then once a seller uploads the video file, the capture is created. The video is uploaded directly into the same order as one of the params.  It's sort of like fiverrr... you don't get charged until the seller has completed the order - as a way to think about it.

Comment: you can add a column to the order like pending , and then the seller update it to be approved , then the customer can make the payment , am right ?

Comment: What about just having a Video table with just an order_id association with "validates :order_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true" and from the orders model, a "has_one :video" --- would that make it so each order can only have one possible upload with no chance of overriding?

Comment: Na, it needs to be convenient.  And i already have the customers order ID with their card info, all i need to do is capture it once complete.The only thing i need is something to allow only one video upload and to never allow an update or edit to that video once uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a callback with `ActiveModel::Dirty` to initiate a rollback on any change after [changing](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) the column value to anything *not* from empty or nil.

```
class Amount < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Dirty

  before_save :check_video

  attr_accessor :video # or whatever your video attribute is

  private

  def check_video
    false if video_changed? && !video_was.nil? # or empty or whatever
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: this would go into my order controller? or a new one?  And its built with the video column directly into the order row itself at the moment.

Comment: sorry if im being pushy but im wondering whats going on here.  Would this be used if I were to create a separate table for uploading videos (that is associated with orders) ? or is this something I would put directly into the orders model?

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure in the model layer that a record cannot be updated anymore once it was successfully created.

One simple way might be to override the [`readonly?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-readonly-3F) method that is used by Rails to check for read-only records internally:

```
# in your model
def readonly?
  super || video.present? && persisted?
end
```

Calling `save` on a read-only instance will raise an `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord` exception.

With this method, you can write `if @order.readonly?` in your controller and view to check if the `@order` is still updatedable.

Comment: Okay,  so this will turn the video column into read only once its successfully uploaded?  as you see in my update, i did find a way to solve my issue.  What do you think about having both? or which one would you suggest if just having one? I'm fairly new at this and looking for a bit of guidance on this

Comment: Keep in mind that you code in the controller only protect actions done in the context of this controller. When you add for example an API or an admin interface then you will need to have the same protection there. Therefore a protection in the model layer is important too because it ensure that every controller and even manually method call in the Rails console cannot bypass this protection. Therefore I would argue you need both a protection in the model layer and checks in the view leyer to not show links to actions that are invalid anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, i have the views covered.   As for your code above.  All the model needs is that code and then in the update action the @order.readonly? and boom? nothing more?

Comment: Exacty? Use `@order.readonly?` in the controller and views to check the condition instead of `@order.video.present?. And even if there wasn't that condition in the controller, the model would disallow changes just because the method `readonly?` exists. No more callbacks or filters needed at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a controller only for uploading the video files.

This way I can create the upload with the charges code in the create, and then allow updating without the need to separate the updates...

This is the gist of the controller so far:

```
def create

    @video_order = VideoOrder.new(video_order_params)
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])

    @video_order.order_id = @order.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.video_order.present?
          format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Already complete dog!.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @video_order }
        else

      if @video_order.valid?
        begin
          charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
            :amount      => (@order.order_price).to_i * 100,
            :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
            :currency    => 'usd',
            :customer => @order.stripe_customer_token,
            :destination => {
              :amount => @amount_seller ,
              :account => (@order.seller.stripe_token),
            }
          })
        rescue Stripe::CardError => e
          charge_error = e.message
        end
        if charge_error
          flash[:error] = charge_error
          redirect_to '/'
        else

          if @video_order.save
            @order.update_column(:order_status, 2)
            format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Video order was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @video_order }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @video_order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

  # PATCH/PUT /video_orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /video_orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @video_order.update(video_order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to user_order_path([@user, @order]), notice: 'Video order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @video_order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @video_order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I also have preventative measures in the create method just in case.

Comment: I’m not exactly sure what your database structure is, but if you have a uniqueness validation in place on the model to ensure that a video isn’t charged twice, you really should additionally add that as a constraint in the database. ActiveRecord code is subject to race conditions when determining uniqueness (if they double click and two requests happen, they both could be processed). The database would enforce that this doesn’t get saved, though you’ll still need to handle possibly reverting the charge in the case that the transaction error happens when calling @video_order.save.

Comment: I changed that situation.  It allows a video to be changed but when changed/updated, it won't create a charge.  Just in case people mess up and upload a wrong video i allow for it.  I was initially concerned with charging when uploading a new video, or stopping an upload in its tracks and starting over or some other malicious type of things that could possible happen.  i feel like i have a good amount of measures in the controller to avoid that